# Checkbox onCheck not working properly in javascript React native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a function for Checkbox check as shown below:

The Checkbox component looks like this :

But the function doesn't work properly, its not adding the values properly. The same value is getting added twice.Can someone please help me resolve this?

Comment: Hii, use State for updating your CheckBox value..

Comment: @Mr.vdtarsariya Check and uncheck is working properly. But I am not able to get the correct sum result on check and uncheck.

Comment: what is selectedArrayOBJ? can you please share